# PHP select all where date is after now

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a system with different classes and lectures that my users can sign up for.  There is a last date for the sign up that date stored in the data base like: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

On the front page, I want to show when the last sign up for the next classes is. I want to be able to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM classes WHERE last_reg < now()
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it:

```
SELECT * FROM classes WHERE last_reg > curdate()
```

You want to compare the last registration date with the current date and select what is not closed - or still available.

I flipped the less than to a greater than, otherwise you would only be selecting the items that were already closed.

Working with dates is no different to working with numbers - except that you get to use a bunch [more date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that are in MySQL already.

For example, with numbers, if you wanted to find anything less than 10 you would put in `field<10` and that would be it, but if you want to use a date that is for example, more than ten days ago, you have to start using the date functions like this:

```
select * from SomeTable where dateField<date_sub(curdate, interval 10 day)
```